# Firebase realtime database halt after reaching 29k+ data

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database

Our firebase real-time database reaches 29k+, after that our app keeps on loading and loading and not showing any more data. i used this script to populate data return from firebase:

```
firebase.database().ref('/registrant/').orderByChild('id').on("value", function(snapshot) {

 console.log(snapshot.val());

});
```

any help will be much appreciated thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Along with Franks answer, you could also do a staggered approach where you use a shallow query to get the top-level elements and load them asynchronously.

To my knowledge it is only available to the rest API, but it gives you the root nodes to iterate through directly

```js
import request from 'request';

request({ url: "https://[YOUR-APP-ID].firebaseio.com/path/to/data.json?shallow=true" }, (error, response, body) => {
    const shallowData = JSON.parse(body);
    console.log(shallowData);
});
```

Source:

- https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/retrieve-data#shallow
- https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/database#section-param-shallow

Comment: I only getting uid and boolean value:
{
    "-MfipzziyO49svrPcbkC": true,
    "-MfipmuMXzKPeHVU4tnA": true,
    "-MfpswXLsYEUSIkVgNES": true,
    "-Mfiq0nD6Z2yn81FqfnP": true,
    "-MfipnTBCoYTioD3oQg-": true,
    "-MfipeEzKLyJQZm6MpWO": true,
    "-MfipenPm8W1IW-mvT6a": true,
    "-MfipeMLDqH8MHMvRQ9R": true,
    "-MfipiVxq9bJAOF_L5Ha": true,
    "-Mfiq355V-nWtEPAU_6a": true.......

Comment: that is the expected result of a `shallow` query, it only returns the key names. You will have to loop through each key to fetch them in batches, you can use starting points, queries, etc. this ensures you get the base information without bloating your bandwidth

Answer (score 0):

If you're loading 29K nodes, is it possible that you're running low on memory in where it is that you're running this code?

If so, consider loading less data by for example by add a `limit...` clause to your query:

```
firebase.database().ref('/registrant/').orderByChild('id').limitToFirst(100).on("value", function(snapshot) {
  ...
```

Comment: thanks for the response frank, I did however limit the display but the problem still persists, and this error show :
FIREBASE INTERNAL ERROR: Server Error: The specified payload is too large, please request a location with less data.

any advice?

Comment: Interesting. Did you [define an index](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/indexing-data) on `id`?

Comment: yep frank have this:
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true,
    "registrant": {
      ".indexOn": ".value"
  }
}
}
what do u think?

Answer (score 0):

Alright got it to work this is derived from Frank and DIGI's answer kudos to them what i did is this:

let start = 20;
let end = 30;

```
$scope.execute = function() {

    start = start + 10;
    end = end + 10;

    var settings = {
        "url": "https://lcqrregistry-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/registrant.json?orderBy=\"age\"&startAt=" + start + "&endAt=" + end + "&print=pretty",
        "method": "GET",
        "timeout": 0,
    };

    $.ajax(settings).done(function(response) {

        console.log(start,end)

        $timeout(function() {
            $scope.$apply(function() {
                let returnArr = [];
                angular.forEach(response, function(value, key) {
                    returnArr.push(value);
                });
                $scope.registereds = returnArr;
                console.log($scope.registereds)
            });
        })

    });

}

var settings = {
    "url": "https://my-url/registrant.json?orderBy=\"age\"&startAt=" + 18 + "&endAt=" + 30 + "&print=pretty",
    "method": "GET",
    "timeout": 0,
};

$.ajax(settings).done(function(response) {

    $timeout(function() {
        $scope.$apply(function() {
            let returnArr = [];
            angular.forEach(response, function(value, key) {
                returnArr.push(value);
            });
            $scope.registereds = returnArr;
            console.log($scope.registereds)
        });
    })

});
I filter by age and just add the next button to populate the filtered data
```

Comment: yah as I wanted to give more updates I can only give 1 sorry guy but still frank and Digi byte u rocks